# Skinning test at interview

Tags: css

I had an interview on the phone for a front end web developer position. Afterwards, I got a call back saying they would like me to go in person and give me a skinning test. I've been trying to find out more about this skinning test but no luck. Anyone knows wth a skinning test is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely they will give you a webpage design in Photoshop or some similar design tool and then ask you to ["skin"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_%28computing%29) it, i.e. create a working webpage using front end technologies like HTML, CSS, Javascript, images, icons etc from the design prototype.

Also most likely it will be a fairly simple page design where their goal is to test if you have to good to produce deliverable that are expected from that title -- Front End Web Developer. In other words, don't get scared that it will be some huge complex test.

Comment: Ahh I see. That makes sense. The lady said I will have access to their dropbox for 2 hours and within those 2 hours I will have to create this website from what I assume is a psd file since she mentioned Photoshop a few times. This will be done from home surprisingly. Wednesday at noon :)

Comment: There you go! Atleast you have some idea now. I would suggest you take any free PSD or buy one from http://themeforest and try to skin it before wednesday so you can "kill" the interview and look like you could do it blind-folded. Good Luck!

Comment: I will definitely practice doing this "skinning" but I will be given specific instructions on Wednesday on what to make or w.e Thank you again

Comment: Let us know how it goes!